# How to set flux cron expression for seconds to schedule an event?

Tags: flux, reactjs-flux, cron-task

I would like to schedule an event for every 15 seconds and must use *flux library*.

Using *'0 0 +15'* I'm able to set a schedule to run every 15 minutes,

However, when I tried for 15 sec my event is not picked up.

Any ideas on how I can resolve this?

Comment: Did you try checking this doc https://doc.flux.ly/display/flux80/Time+Expressions ?

Comment: Yes i am referring this documentation only but still there is no clue

Comment: This was configuration issue for me. The cron expression is '0 +15'  to trigger the event in every 15 second.